# How to split a string in python based on any combination of semicolon, whitespace and comma?

Tags: python, split

I want to split a string separated by any combination of semicolon, whitespace and comma. For example:

input:`"Jan,Feb;Mar Apr,   May;"`

output:`["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May"]`

Because the `split()` method will match exactly what you specify in it, which is not what I need, I can not simply use `split()` method here. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Seems like you want http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split.

Comment: use `re.split()` with an appropriate regular expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `re.split`:

```
>>> [s for s in re.split(r'[ ,;]', '"Jan","Feb";"Mar" "Apr", "May";') if s]
['"Jan"', '"Feb"', '"Mar"', '"Apr"', '"May"']
```

The `if s` filters out empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

`re.findall` looks good here:

```
In [168]: strs='"Jan","Feb";"Mar" "Apr", "May";'

In [169]: import re

In [170]: re.findall(r'\w+',strs)
Out[170]: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally the right answer is regular expressions, but it happens you *can* solve this particular problem with the methods `split` and `replace`:

```
>>> s = "one two,three;four"
>>> s.replace(',',' ').replace(';',' ').split()
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

---

I think [Ashwini's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/ashwini-chaudhary) is best - rather than try to remove all separating crud, just search for the useful content.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning regex, but providing a lighterweight string replace/split solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an elegant non regex solution using `str.translate` followed by `str.split`

```
>>> in_str = '"Jan","Feb";"Mar" "Apr", "May";'
>>> in_str.translate(None,",; ")[1:-1].split("\"\"")
['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
import re

c = b'"Jan","Feb";"Mar" "Apr", "May"';
needle = r'("[^, ;]*")'
r = re.compile(needle)

months = r.findall(c)
print months
```